# Nest JS - Unable to inject service to middlewere

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have created an auth middlewere for checking each request, the middlewere is using server (only if data was not found in the req.connection).
I'm trying to inject the service into my middlewere and I keep getting the same error "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthenticationMiddleware (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context."

AuthenticationModule:

```
@Module({
   imports: [ServerModule],
   controllers: [AuthenticationMiddleware],
})
export class AuthenticationModule {
}
```

AuthenticationMiddleware:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

constructor(private readonly service : UserService) {}

resolve(): (req, res, next) => void {
 return (req, res, next) => {
   if (req.connection.user)
    next();

  this.service.getUsersPermissions()     
  }
}
```

ServerModule:

```
@Module({
 components: [ServerService],
 controllers: [ServerController],
 exports: [ServerService]
})    
 export class ServerModule {}
```

ApplicationModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CompanyModule,
    ServerModule,
    AuthenticationModule
  ]
})

export class ApplicationModule implements NestModule{
  configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer): void {
  consumer.apply(AuthenticationMiddleware).forRoutes(
      { path: '/**', method: RequestMethod.ALL }
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your application can't resolve `AuthMiddleware` dependencies probably because you inject an `UserService` into it but the `ServerModule` that you import into your `AuthenticationModule`just exports a `ServerService`. So, what should be made is:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

  constructor(private readonly service : ServerService) {}

  resolve(): (req, res, next) => void {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      if (req.connection.user)
        next();

    this.service.getUsersPermissions()     
  }
}
```

You can find more about the NestJS dependency container [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dependency-injection).